# How to get names of files from a folder and add them to a tree widget as children in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I am making a program that needs to be able to output the names of files from a specific folder as items in a Tree Widget but I cannot seem to figure it out. I managed to do it in a list widget without too much hassle but I cant get that code to work with a tree widget. Below is the code I wrote to get the described functionality with a list widget

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

   QString path = "C:/Program Files/GUI_Project/bin";
    QDir dir(path);
    if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkpath(path);
        }
    QDir myPath(path);
    myPath.setFilter(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    MyList = myPath.entryList();
    ui->listWidget->addItems(MyList);
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html

Comment: The problem with that is I dont want any directories displayed, just the names of the file in a specific folder

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a `QFileSystemModel` and use `setRootPath("your/path")` to create a model of a folder. You can use `setFilter()` to decide what is shown [Filter List](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum).Then you can add that model to a `QTreeView`. It's just like a `QTreeWidget` except it has much better performance and is the better option for most use cases imo. For example, if a file gets added or deleted from that directory, the model will change and update in your program. A `QTreeWidget` can't do that.

```
QFileSystemModel *dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(); //Create new model
dirModel->setRootPath("C:/Program Files/GUI_Project/bin"); //Set model path
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::Files); //Only show files

ui->treeView->setModel(dirModel); //Add model to QTreeView

QModelIndex idx = dirModel->index("C:/Program Files/GUI_Project/bin"); //Set the root item
ui->treeView->setRootIndex(idx);
```

If you want to stick with a `QTreeWidget` however, you will have to recursively iterate over a folders contents and add each item individually.

Comment: I dont want the user to be able to see their drives in the program though, they should only be able to see the folder and the items in it, nothing else

Comment: All of those things are configurable via setFilter http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum. And setting a rootPath and the root item makes your selected folder the root object. Please reread over my post and you can see this. This is what I use in my projects all the time. Here is an example I use in one of my old programs: https://i.gyazo.com/1bf1c355802546d6001c5633205b3460.png This is just the contents of a directory

Comment: Did you implement this yet? This would be the correct way to go what you're after. If so, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You simply iterate over your input list and create a `QTreeWidgetItem` object for each entry.

If you pass the tree widget as the parent it will become a top level item in the tree, if you pass another tree widget item as the parent, it becomes a child entry of that item.

Comment: Would this work if the amount of items in the folder changes randomly?

Comment: @Nick No it wouldn't, as I explained in my answer. My answer is the way to go bro :/

Comment: @Nick you could of course rebuild the items whenever necessary, but as mc360pro said, a model based approach would do this more nicely.